# How does a sigma expression become equivalent to a closed form expression?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Can anyone explain how does $f(x) = \sum_{i=0} ^\infty \frac{x}{2^i}$ become the closed form expression of $f(x) = 2x$?

Basically I want to know how to take a sigma expression and make it close form.

Thanks

Comment: You are summing nothing

Comment: Sorry, I edited my post. It should be bit more clear now.

Comment: There isn't any general method that will work for all summations, but it's useful to know about geometric series so you can handle summations like this one.

Answer (score 1):

The *finite sum*
$$
1+{1\over 2}+{1\over 2^2}+\cdots+{1\over 2^n}=2-{1-{1\over 2^n}{1\over 2}\over 1-{1\over 2}}=2-{1\over 2^n}
$$
has $\lim$ that is *by definition* the sum of the *series*:
$$
f(x) = \sum_{i=0}^\infty\frac{x}{2^i}=x\sum_{i=0}^\infty\frac{1}{2^i}
= x\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=0}^n\frac{1}{2^i}=x2.
$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

> $$ \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} t^i = \frac{1}{1-t},\quad |t|<1.$$

Comment: Only for certain values of $t$. Surely, you're not one of those who claim that $1 + 2 + 4 + 8 + \cdots = -1$?

Comment: @mrf: Of course, you need the condition $|t|<1$. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 0):

This is the well-known [sum of a geometric series](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GeometricSeries.html), where the $x$ has been factored out and we're left with a geometric series of common ratio $1/2$.

An infinite series (sum) is calculated by summing the first $n$ terms and taking the limit as $n\to\infty$. You should find an analysis textbook and read the chapters on infinite series.